# wxPython ObjectListView widget not clickable or scrollable

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, objectlistview, objectlistview-python

I created an ObjectListView in wxPython and can't seem to click anything on it (scrollbars, sorting, etc):

```
self.requests_view = ObjectListView(parent=self.panel.pages["server"],
                                    id=wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
self.requests_view.SetColumns([a bunch of column definitions])
self.requests_view.EnableSorting()
self.h_sizers["server"][1].AddStretchSpacer(prop=1)
self.h_sizers["server"][1].Add(self.requests_view, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
self.h_sizers["server"][1].AddStretchSpacer(prop=1)
```

I went through and changed all my threading code to multiprocessing to make sure it wasn't the sleep intervals preventing my interaction.  I can click tabs on my toolbar just fine.  How can I make this widget "clickable"?

What I've tried:

- I changed all my threading code to multiprocessing code to prevent the sleep counts from locking out the gui.
- Tried extending all wx.Timers to much longer intervals in case that was locking out clicks
- Checked for any click event binds (none), all sleeps (none)
- Tried to mess around with the parent/child relationships, but it's how it should be
- Searched google for wxpython issues in general and objectlistview issues in particular.  Also scoured the objectlistview source code for a setting that might enable clicking.
- EDIT: Gave the widget an absolute size just in case it was being expanded by the gui and the click areas weren't.

Comment: Above snippet is not enough to see what is going wrong.  Can you make a self contained sample - http://wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps

Comment: I suspect that your widget hierarchy has an issue, i.e. some other widget is on top of the widget or .....

Comment: Did you try any of the olv demo's? Are they working for you?

Comment: I made a sample example and it works fine so I'm digging through the other areas to figure out the problem.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that it is not getting focus, add a print statement to each `wx.timer` to test what is firing and in what order.